# Test Manager but no TFS access

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs, mtm

I am new to VS Test manager and trying to do some practice. I do not have access to any TFS. Is there a dummy TFS on web that can be used for this purpose? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Team Services](https://beta.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-team-services-vs/) is a good option. You can get started for free, and the first 5 users in your team are also FREE.

After creating an account for VSTS, create a team project, and check whether you  get a Test tab on Web Access.